# How to encrypt a password using MD5-DES?

Tags: security, encryption, md5

I'm looking for any available tool/shell command which can encrypt passwords using as algorithm "masked-MD5-DES". The masked password must be then converted into base64, but that should be the easy part.
In the only working example I have found, the string "password" is encrypted as "j37uUs8kG9t2QSWjoxxtDg=="

```
<credentials>
    <masked-password iteration-count="12" salt="12345678" masked-password="j37uUs8kG9t2QSWjoxxtDg=="/>
</credentials>
```

Can you help me to generate that masked password from the clear text "password" ?
I have tried with:

```
echo "password" | md5sum | base64
```

However the result does not match with "j37uUs8kG9t2QSWjoxxtDg==". 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: As requested by comment, I've added a reference to the document which contains the algorithm to be used in the application: https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-proposals/blob/master/elytron/ELY-816-masked-password.adoc

Thanks

Comment: Any specific link to the definition of "masked-password"? There are several password hashes, but you don't see many that include both a cryptographic hash (MD5) *and* a block cipher (DES). There are  a surprising amount of options to combine a password, character encoding, salt and iteration count after all, and I've got no idea how DES is used in this scheme.

Comment: Thanks. I have linked the only doc I have, which contains the only example of masked password using the mentioned algorithm. I'm trying to generate that masked password from the clear text "password"

Comment: Read it, tried looking it up, found that it contains everything *but* the algorithm specification. Perfect. Out of time, need to do stuff, sorry. I think you could try PBKDF1 in Java using MD5 and DES, there should be examples around. Then just base 64 the result. Of course all completely insecure because, well DES and no IV.\

Comment: I'm not very much in this world of wildfly... but the document you posted says it's a *proposal*, not that it's implemented.  

I'm also going to make an assumption that the intended function will have a concatenation of an Initialization Vector (IV) as a part of the encoded string.  Said IV used with a non ECB mode of DES (or any block cipher) will result in a different "random" looking string every time you encrypt the same string of password.  You will still be able to get back to the original "password" with the correct IV/Key

Comment: @Kritner That would be logical, however:  "This will require not using the initialization vectors (IV) randomly generated by the javax.crypto.Cipher as that makes decryption impossible" .. nothing logical about this proposal.

Comment: oh... that's interesting, and sounds uh, not so great?

Comment: Compared to using DES in a proposal it is extremely sane.

Comment: It's **NOT** a proposal. It's been implemented in July 2019. Here is the PR details - [https://github.com/wildfly-security/wildfly-elytron/pull/1297](https://github.com/wildfly-security/wildfly-elytron/pull/1297). If you are interested in list of supported algorithms - [https://github.com/wildfly-security/wildfly-elytron/blob/1.x/credential/base/src/main/java/org/wildfly/security/password/interfaces/MaskedPassword.java#L38](https://github.com/wildfly-security/wildfly-elytron/blob/1.x/credential/base/src/main/java/org/wildfly/security/password/interfaces/MaskedPassword.java#L38)